# select_tag within form always submits a blank string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I want to submit some information that isn't a column on a model, so I'm using a select_tag:

```
= form_for [:admin, @post] do |f|
  = f.error_messages

  %p
    = select_tag :category_name, options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :id, :category_name)
  ...
```

It generates html that looks right:

```
<form id="edit_post_1" class="edit_post" method="post" action="/admin/admin_posts/1" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
<p>
<select id="category_name" name="category_name">
<option value="6">City</option>
<option value="7">College</option>
<option value="8">Sports</option>
<option value="9">Work</option>
</select>
</p>
<p>
<label for="subcat_prefix">Subcategory Name</label>
```

But the Rails controller always sees `"category_name"=>"",` in the params.  I'm missing something obvious, but what?

Edit: server log on submitting:

```
Started POST "/admin/admin_posts/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-22 15:06:52 -0800
  Processing by Admin::AdminPostsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"CmG+YPFuaKfg+liipxJI6PKQHmbdJ4m2VtJmeD2dRqk=", "post"=>{"subcat_prefix"=>"In", "subtopic_name"=>"City perferendis", "post_content"=>"Explicabo dolor totam fuga voluptatem nam voluptatibus voluptatibus beatae aliquam ducimus et voluptate deleniti dignissimos et. Eum ipsam quos quo voluptas laboriosam delectus adipisci veniam similique libero eaque dolor dolorem libero autem ex aliquam non"}, "category_name"=>"", "commit"=>"Update Post", "id"=>"1"}
```

Comment: Can you post what your log says on receiving that request?

Comment: Done, see post.  I see a blank string if I select something or leave the default option selected (which is just the first choice)

Comment: Well what I can think of is: check the html if there is any other element with the same name `document.querySelectorAll('[name=category_name]')` since it could be overwriting the submitted value, test with different browser (might be some weird bug), try to create a reduced test case which replicates the error...

Comment: It would be useful to see a more complete HTML snippet than just the field *(which itself has nothing wrong with it)*.

Comment: @JakubHampl, you were right.  I had a hidden field lower in the form with the same name.  It didn't even occur to me that Rails sets the id on the select field.  If you rewrite an answer with your comment I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be another field with the same name lower which is overwriting the value.

Check with running `document.querySelectorAll('[name=category_name]')` in your js console.

Comment: Thanks for providing the javascript selector.  I tried testing this with the jQuery selector and only got one result.

Comment: i want to + this a million times, thanks a lot @Jakub Hampl this really helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

`select_tag :category_name`

try

`f.select :category_name`

Comment: That won't work because `category_name` is not a column on the `@post` model.